# Merge image and audio to make movie file using iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Is it possible to merge an image and audio file to create a movie file (like a .avi) using the iPhone SDK?  If so does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now with AVFoundation. Refer to this question for the code: [AVFoundation + AssetWriter: Generate Movie With Images and Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640657/avfoundation-assetwriter-generate-movie-with-images-and-audio)