# Making a movie file with selected images in iPhone

Tags: ios4

Is there any code regarding making a movie file with some selected images in iPhone? I need to create a movie file from the images, not the animations. I am working a few months in Objective-C. That's why I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question might help you: [AVFoundation + AssetWriter: Generate Movie With Images and Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640657/avfoundation-assetwriter-generate-movie-with-images-and-audio)